# MySQL subquery - get latest timestamped record and extract field

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that gets the records of a table, and counts the number of related records for that table.

What I'd like to do is get the `text` field of the most recent record of a related table and include it in the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    inst.id, inst.name, inst.state, inst.farm_status,
    (SELECT COUNT(inst_note.id) 
        FROM project_institution_note AS inst_note
        WHERE inst_note.institution_id = inst.id) AS inst_note_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog AS c
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id 
        AND c.status = 0 
        AND c.catalog_type BETWEEN 0 AND 1) AS ug_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog AS c
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id 
        AND c.status = 0 
        AND c.catalog_type BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AS grad_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog AS c
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id 
        AND c.status = 0 
        AND c.catalog_type >= 3) AS alt_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog_note AS cn
        INNER JOIN farmtool_catalog AS c
        ON c.id = cn.catalog_id
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id) AS catalog_note_count,
    (SELECT inst_note.text FROM project_institution_note AS inst_note  -- Issue portion of query
        LEFT JOIN project_institution AS inst
        ON inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
        WHERE inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
        ORDER BY inst_note.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS latest_note
FROM project_institution AS inst
LEFT JOIN project_institution_note AS inst_note
ON inst.id = inst_note.institution_id
LEFT JOIN project_catalog AS c
ON inst.id = c.institution_id
WHERE LOWER(inst.state) = "me";
```

What is happening here is it picks up the last record in `project_institution_note` and serves up `text` as the value in the query.  With this sub-query, how can I

1. limit the selection of `project_institution_note` to the related `project_institution.id` AND
2. select the most recent timestamped record.

I've already accomplished #2, but I need help limiting the result set in #1.  Any ideas?

Comment: show us sample data and expected output.  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the thing is your show us too much data isnt relevent to your question. So try to reduce the code to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The latest record, eh?  That is, the record from `project_institution_note` with the most recent `date` value?

If  `project_institution_note`  has an `id` column that's autoincrementing, and you only ever INSERT and never UPDATE that table, this is easy. Here's a subquery that gets the latest `text` value for each `institution_id`.

```
                  SELECT a.institution_id, a.text
                    FROM project_institution_note a
                    JOIN (   SELECT MAX(id) id
                               FROM project_institution_note
                              GROUP BY institution_id
                         ) b ON a.id = b.id
```

That basically uses the list of maximum `id` values for each institution to look up the latest `text`.

If you MUST use the `date` column, it's slightly harder, but follows the same pattern.  (If two `date` values are identical, you get two results from this.)

```
                  SELECT a.institution_id, a.text
                    FROM project_institution_note a
                    JOIN (   SELECT institution_id,
                                    MAX(date) date
                               FROM project_institution_note
                              GROUP BY institution_id
                         ) b  ON a.date = b.date
                             AND a.institution_id = b.institution_id
```

You can then use this as an independent (uncorrelated) subquery and join it to your other stuff. Here's an example

```
  SELECT inst.id, inst.name, inst.state, inst.farm_status,
         note.text
    FROM project_institution inst
    LEFT JOIN (
                /* the subquery from above */
         ) note ON inst.id = note.institution_id
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` prevents the query from suppressing results where no notes exist.

You have lots of dependent subqueries in your query. MySQL is *horrible* at dependent subqueries. You may want to refactor them as independent subqueries and join them instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution.

As part of the field declaration in `SELECT`, I define `inst.id`, which is coming from `project_institution`.  Inside of the SELECT subquery, I also say I want `inst.id` from `project_institution, which re-declares that alias.

Changing `inst` inside the subquery

```
SELECT inst_note.text FROM project_institution_note AS inst_note
    LEFT JOIN project_institution AS `inst`
    ON inst_note.institution_id = `inst.id`
    WHERE inst_note.institution_id = `inst.id`
```

to `institution`, and `institution.id`, respectively, did the trick.